# Is $H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega)$ compactly embedded on $H_0^1(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Considering $\Omega$ bounded and $\partial \Omega$ smooth. 
I already know that $H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega)$ is continuously embedded on $H_0^1(\Omega)$, thus if I take a bounded sequence in $H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega)$ it is also bounded on $H_0^1(\Omega)$, and it has a weakly convergent subsequence, but I didn't succeed with that approach. I also tried to use Rellich Theorem that gives me a strongly convergent subsequence $u_{k_j}$ on $ L^{2}(\Omega)$ when I take $ \{ u_k\}\subset H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega) : \|u_k\|_{H^2(\Omega)}\leq M $. Because $u_k$ is also bounded on $H_0^1(\Omega)$. But then I don't know how to make 
$$\int\limits_\Omega |Du_{k_j}|^2$$
convergent.
Can anyone please help me with that? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ...Are you sure that all of $H^2$ is embedded in $H^1_0$? Or do you mean that $H^2 \cap H^1_0$ is continuously embedded in $H^1_0$? (Think about the 1D case, where Sobolev functions are continuous; an $H^2$ function needn't vanish on the boundary, but an $H^1_0$ function does have to vanish there.)

Comment: completely true, my problem was in $H^2\cap H_0^1$, but I still don't know how to prove it

Comment: For that, I suspect the answer is no. My idea here is that the image of $\partial_{x_i}$ over all of $H^2 \cap H^1_0$ seems like it should be $H^1$ modulo constants (i.e. $I^{-1}(\{ 0 \})$ where $I : H^1 \to \mathbb{R},I(f)=\int_\Omega f dx$). Can you try and play with that idea?

Comment: The problem is that I've asked this because I saw it used in Evans's book, page 506, and this was the kind of result that I needed to understand what he did.

Comment: Which edition? I see nothing of this sort on page 506 of the second edition (which is talking about calculus of variations).

Comment: I don't know, it says Volume 19, anyway it is on Chapter 9, Nonvariational techniques, Theorem 5 about existence of the solution of a problem via Schaefer's fixed point theorem. Thank you very much for your help :D

Comment: So you're really asking about the question: if $\| A[u] \|_{H^2} \leq C(\| u \|_{H^1_0} + 1)$ and $u_k \to u$ in $H^1_0$ then $A[u_k]$ has a subsequence which converges strongly in $H^1_0$. I think that much is just Rellich, since $A[u_k]$ and $\nabla A[u_k]$ are both bounded sequences in $H^1$. So Rellich gets you a subsequence with $A[u_{k_j}]$ converging in $L^2$, then apply Rellich to that to get a subsequence with $\nabla A[u_{k_{j_\ell}}]$ converging in $L^2$. I am not sure whether that implies the actual result in your question. (You're actually further along in the subject than I am.)

Comment: That works, actually it was very simple, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As Ian suggested, the statement follows by applying the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem to the gradients.

Generally, any time you apply the Sobolev embedding on a bounded domain and give up a bit in the exponent of the target space, the embedding is compact. An intuitive reason is that when exponents are related in this way,  small scale features affect the norm of the source space much more than they affect the norm of the target space. So, with a uniform norm bound you have a collection of functions that all live in the same bounded domain and whose features are limited in scale from below. There are only so many substantially different photographs of given size and given resolution.